# Method 'Parent' of object failed

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have MS Access 2013 and I'm trying to make a search form that populates other details when a row inside a subform is selected. I figured out how to get which row is selected, and which column, but now I need to pass that information to the parent form so I can populate the other things on the form.

So on my form's subform, I made an On Click event:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form_Click()
     MsgBox(Me.Name) ' returns P_pat subform
     MsgBox(Me.Parent.Name) ' says 'Parent' failed
```

But it can never find its parent. I also tried on a few other events but the results were the same. The Access form looks like this:

[image]

The highlighted subform is the one I'm trying to work with, and I want it to call the parent so that the parent can populate its other child subform (the one below the highlighted form).

I feel like I slammed into a brick wall that shouldn't be there and my pride hurts.

How do I get the parent?

I know that I can simply set the record ID I selected with a global variable, but I have no way of triggering an update event for the other subform.

Any help or advice?

Comment: Maybe try looking here: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0031.htm

Comment: You code is correct so maybe you face some other issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't look like there is anything at all wrong with your code.  So from research there seem to be three possible solutions that I have found so far:

1. Make sure there are no special characters in your forms' names
2. Compact and repair
3. Create a new blank project and import all of your database into the blank project

Comment: There were no special characters, compact and repair didn't help. I didn't have the heart to start over again because there's over 50 tables and some number of forms. But I did figure out that creating a new form and copy-pasting all my controls and code did the trick!

Comment: That's good, it just seemed like something "broke" on the form.  Those last two steps are my go to solutions on issues that I can't find answers for.  The 3rd one might be a bit of a shotgun approach though.  Though when you use the import system it is pretty much a Select All > Okay then go for break while it runs.